# How to add databases to smart contract?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets, database

I creating dApp and I want to add some sort of registration pannel(add nickname to wallet address)
and its nessesary to store this data on db (public wallet address, nickname, email(optionally)). So
can I make a function which can add this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you have somewhat complex data that you expect to be used mostly every time I would suggest mapping address to an object.

Declare the object:

```
struct registration = {
    string nickname; 
    string email;
}
```

Then create the mapping:

*mapping(address -> registration) database;*

You can set the data by calling:

```
database[targetAddress].nickname = newNickname;
database[targetAddress].email = newEmail; // leave black to keep the initialization value ""
```

Or

```
database[targetAddress] = registration(newNickname, newEmail);
database[targetAddress] = registration(newNickname, ); // if you wanted to initialize to "" in this case
```